# AngularJS: find the index position from directive with data in ng-init statements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-init

How I can do to show the correct data when I click on that item. I have my directive which compile a template when I click and I want that when you click on that element data show me that element and not the last value that I have in my json. For example, I have 1 2 3 item and when I click on the first item I want to display the data of the first element and not the data of the last element.

**Html containing the attribute ng-init with data:**

```
<li ng-init='product = {id: "<%=product.id%>", brand: "<%=product.name_short%>", descriptionExcerpt: "", price: "", priceBefore: "", priceDiscount: "", mainImage: "<%=raw(main_image.url(:huge))%>", masterVariant: {id: "<%=product.master.id%>"}, variants: [{id: "0", name: "ASDasd", price: "£123", available: true }, {id: "1", name: "ASDwegwagasd", price: "£13", available: false }]}' preview-product index="$index">
  <div class="sd-product-container">
    <div class="sd-product-image">
      <a itemprop="image" href="<%= url %>">
        <img src="<%= raw(image_url) if image_url %>" itemprop="image" alt="<%= product.name %>" width="244" height="244" />
      </a>
      <div class="sd-product-options">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sd-product-description">
      <h4><%= product.brand.name.html_safe %></h4>
      <span>
        <%= link_to truncate(product.name_short, length: 100), url, class: 'product-name', itemprop: 'name' %>
      </span>

      <% if product.teaser.present? %>
        <span class="sd-small-caps">
          <%= link_to strip_tags(product.teaser), url %>
        </span>
      <% end %>
      <%= render partial: 'spree/products/price', locals: { product: product, current_currency: current_currency } %>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

**My Directive:**

```
(function (){

  "use strict";

  var app = angular.module('quickPreview');

  app.directive('previewProduct', function ($compile,$templateCache) {

      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            index: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


          element.bind('click', '.sd-click-preview', function (){
                var preview = angular.element($templateCache.get('quickpreview.html'));
                var cpreview = $compile(preview);
                element.append(preview);
                cpreview(scope);
                console.log(cpreview(scope));

          });

        }
    };

  });

}(window, window.angular));
```

**My template where I need to paint the data**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="quickpreview.html">
<div class="content-preview">
    <div class="content-preview-inner">
        <span class="full-preview"></span>
        <span class="close-preview"></span>
        <div class="block block-left left">
            <div class="content-tabs">
                <div class="tabs-content vertical">
                    <div class="content active" id="panel1">
                        <div class="content-details">
                            <div class="details">
                                <h3 class="title-product">{{product.brand}}</h3>
                                <h2 class="short-desc">{{product.descriptionExcerpt}}</h2>
                                <div class="block-price">{{product.descriptionExcerpt}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content-img">
                            <div class="main-img">
                                <img ng-src="{{product.mainImage}}" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!

With just read some documentation about angular I could figure it out

just had to add this line in my directive:

```
scope: true
```

When using Isolated Scope with Attributes.

[Here I leave a link where they explain Isolated Scope With Attributes](https://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/)